# How to copy only small files

Tags: file-transfer

I am using Windows. I have a folder with many subfolders. Inside are a lot of unorganized files. Some are a few KB's. Others a few GB's. I want to copy only those files smaller than 100mb. Is that possible? And yes, even though it's messy, I want to preserve their current file structure.

Comment: Which windows are you using. I seem to recall that windows 7 has a search function and you can search all files which match a certain criteria (e.g. not just in folder X, but also with size Y). Find all those files and then just drag-and-drop them to copy.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use robocopy from a command prompt, it has a `max` parameter that would work.

Example:

```
robocopy c:\somefolder d:\destination /s /max:104857600
```